# Ionic AudioToggle Plugin how to use?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

i´m using the media plugin for my ionic project to play audio files.
This is working well. My Question is, if it is possible to change the audio output to the earpiece? I found the plugin 'AudioToggle', but this it not working for me. Could someone show me an example or another way to solve this?

I have added the AudioToggle plugin, but im not able to use it in my project (intellj: cannot find name 'audiotoggle')

Comment: does no one solved this?